# Git commits missing from commit history

Tags: git, gitlab

We are using GitLab and `git` on a `CentOS 7` server, and I've noticed, that some of my files, that I KNOW I've commited got deleted in a later commit.

I've started hunting down, where the error could have occured, where could I have accidentally deleted these files, and I've noticed something very strange.

Consider the following 3 commits from the picture below:

[image: 3 commits on git]

If I search for the missing file, in the first commit, it is there. It was commited using that commit:

[image: tmp_harag_logo.png is there, added with this commit]

If I check in the `Tradeholding Core Update` commit, nothing changes there neither. But if I check the third commit in the row, `updated`, the file is magically disappeared:

[image: no tmp_harag_logo.png]

I've checked the history of each of these 3 commits for the `ticketer` main folder. In the first two, I see all my previous commits in the history, yet in the third, I see, that a bunch of commits are missing, for example the `added personal dropdown to top navigation menu` one, which added the image file.

When we are working, we are using `git flow`, and working on features. Sometimes though, I still commit directly to `develop` when only a quick fix is needed.

How could have that file disappeared? Did we made an error somewhere, and if yes, how can I be sure, and what error it was, so it won't happen again? Or could this be some strange bug in either `GitLab` or `git` itself?

In the meantime, I noticed, that a bunch of other commited files and changes disappeared also, not just this one file. Why is the `updated` commit ignoring all the previous commits that happened before him?

Comment: Are you sure gitlab isn't just showing the files that *were* changed in those commits? If the file wasn't changed in the commit, why would gitlab list it? Can you verify if you're looking at a set of changes in those commits or if you're looking at a snapshot of the repository at that commit?

Comment: I am sure unfortunately. I opened the commit, and then said browse files, so I will see the file structure after the commit, not just the changes. But also, if i check for changes in the third commit, which deleted the file, the file deletion is not even visible there. GitLab just says, that a single file was modified, which is a totally unrelevant file.

Comment: Basically, what is causing this I think, is that somehow, between two of my commits, exactly 10 of my commits were removed from the commit history. But how could this happened?

Comment: Can you see those 10 commits anywhere in the history?

Comment: Yes, I can see it in EVERY other commit, except the `updated` commit. They are only missing from the `updated` commit, but because every later commit takes into consideration the `updated` commit, git deletes and modifies those files accordingly.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen basically, what I am considering now, is there any way I could make git forgot about that `updated` commit, in all of my commits? Because if that would resolve this, I could easily rewrite that single commit on the top of the history list.

Comment: If the commits are still in your history, then the **commits** have not been removed. However, someone (including you) may remove the **changes** those commits introduced by reversing either all the changes or some of them in latter commits. This, however, should show up in the changesets for those commits, assuming gitlab shows changes.

Comment: If in one commit you add a file, and in a latter commit remove the file, those two commits should both show that file, as added in the first and as deleted in the second. I doubt gitlab is hiding deleted files, unless there is filtering/configuration that allows you configure it like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207420/discussion-between-adam-baranyai-and-lasse-v-karlsen).